# trouble with letters in .bat command to copy files from a dvd

Tags: batch-file

I created a .bat file to replace 3 files from a DVD burned into a directory on my PC, the directory in all others the path is fixed, however it has a complication in case of my driver cd player and dvd the letter is j. But in other drivers when inserted the dvd of course the letter will change to f or g or i for example, how to solve this? How exists? because the Type the folder where it will be copied this defined in problem, but how to get and copy all files of this folder specify in or add variants and search type let's assume that the driver is with the letter n as I put in bat to find this folder with those Files and paste inside the folder that I specified? Is it possible?

I have the following .bat: `copy j:\dvd folder\*.* "c:\file of destination` in the pc. This .bat file recognizes the drive J as if it were in any other PC in a universal way let's say, regardless of which PC the bat is fired it will go into that DVD folder will copy and paste in the specified folder in c: windows windows folder Is not the problem, the problem is fixed the problem is this other unit of dvd in which the letters of the unit change from there will not work when clicking this bat because it is in my pc for example in another it will be i, this is the problem.

Comment: `copy "%~D0\dvd folder*.*" "c:\file of destination in the pc"`

Comment: Are you afraid of periods? Please fix your grammar so that people can understand.

Answer (score 1):

> *Think from another perspective.*

---

```
@echo off
copy "%~Dp0Dvd Folder\*.*" "C:\Folder\"
rem We don't need \ in between %~Dp0 and Dvd Folder because %~Dp0 comes with a \
```

Place this `batch file` in your ****DVD  root**** folder.

---

Explanation:

- [`%~Dp0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to leverage the WMI command line:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "CDROM="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC CDROM Where (MediaLoaded='TRUE') Get Drive 2>NUL"'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do If Exist "%CDROM%\DVD Folder\" Set "CDROM=%%B"
If Not Defined CDROM GoTo :EOF

Copy "%CDROM%\DVD Folder\*.*" "%SystemDrive%\Somewhere Existing"

Timeout -1
```