# Get path of found file in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I want to loop through a folder and its subfolders, get all `.jpg` files and run `myapp.exe` on the files where I rename the currently found file's extension. `myapp.exe` takes the full file path as input and a renamed file as output, like so:

```
myapp.exe C:\images\original\210_551_210-768--RJF3823klzw.jpg -o C:\images\original\210_551_210-768--RJF3823klzw.gif
```

I now have this to recursively print the full path of `*.jpg` files.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b/s *.jpg') do echo "%%i" "%%~ni.gif"
```

However, this prints only the filename for the second parameter, whereas I want to include the path of the found file.

How can I include the path of the output file, the second parameter for `myapp.exe`?

Pseudocode:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b/s *.jpg') do myapp.exe "%%i" "<FULLPATH><FILNAME>.gif"
```

Comment: Are you looking for `"%%~dpni.gif"`? And why use the `myapp.exe`, can you not just use the `Rename` command? `Do Ren "%%i" "%~ni.gif"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myapp.exe` actually converts the file instead of simply changing the extension then you can use metavariable expansion, *(see `For /?` for examples)*:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D *.jpg') Do myapp.exe "%%A" "%%~dpnA.gif"
```

---

If you're only replacing the extension the you can just use the `rename` command:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D *.jpg') Do Ren "%%A" "%%~nA.gif"
```

---

In either case you could also change your for loop to:

```bat
For /R %%A In (*.jpg)
```