# %~dp0 not working when used under folder with space in its name

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, executable-jar

I have the code located in this path- **W:\My Project\Missing.jar**...
When i have spaces in my existing folder **"My Project"**(Note: Folder name with space), on running the command **java -jar %~dp0\Missing.jar**, i am getting error as - Error: Unable to access jarfile W:\My, its is not able to locate the jar if i have spaces in my folder name.

But its is working when the folder name is MyProject(Note: Without any space), that means its working if i have the jar file located at **W:\MyProject\Missing.jar**

How i can make it to work even if the folder has spaces

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work) might help to understand if that you are trying to achieve is really possible.

Comment: `%~dp0\Missing.jar` Might be needing it's own quotes within the command.

Comment: @ Romeo- Not able to find anything helpful there..my code code works if i am using under cd even with spaces but not with java -jar

Comment: @JohnKens- Thanks a lot, it worked when used under quotes- have to use like this----> java -jar "%~dp0\Missing.jar" (%~dp0\Missing.jar should be quoted) instead of --> java -jar %~dp0\Missing.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked when used under quotes- have to use like this----> `java -jar "%~dp0\Missing.jar"` (%~dp0\Missing.jar should be quoted) instead of --> `java -jar %~dp0\Missing.jar`

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate question and answer. This is probably one of the top 3 mistakes newbies make with batch files.