# How to use a notepad file full of Server names to execute a command using batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im using the sc command to query the services running on machines and was using code similar to:

```
      sc \\"server_name" query | find "SERVICE_NAME" > servicelist2.txt
```

so basically all the server names are listed in this one notepad file. there are 100+ of them. it is too hard to manually put each name in and write 100+ lines of code. is there a way i can use batch itself to direct to the notepad file and iterate through all the server names written in it and then put them back into the "sc" command?

EDIT: Am on windows btw if it wasnt obvious. Using batch scripts for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a file named **servers.list** in the same directory, you can use this:

```
for /f %%a in (%~d0%~p0servers.list) do (
  ECHO %%a > servicelist2.txt
  sc \\%%a query | find "SERVICE_NAME" > servicelist2.txt
)
```

Comment: what is the first line in the do part of the for loop? What is the function of that ECHO? like what does it output and where?

Comment: @Gutsygibbon - oh, I added that as extra information.  That writes the server name currently being queried to the servicelist2.txt file, before writing out the results of `SC QUERY`. Otherwise, you won't know what the results of each `SC QUERY` belong to.

Comment: Oh ok. lol. One more question, what is the gibberish in the brace brackets of the for loop? I understand the "for /f %%a in" part but the "(%~d0%~p0servers.list)" part is confusing to me.

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file.  `~d` is the current drive, and `~p` is the current path.  Basically it allows the batch file to find the **servers.list** file in the same directory as the executing batch file.

Comment: OH cool. thanks man. I started learning batch yesterday and my boss already wanted me to make a script. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) :

```
OR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN ("C:\My Documents\servers.txt") DO (
 sc \\%%G query | find "SERVICE_NAME" > servicelist2.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo Starting to list query services...
for /f %%i in (servieslist2.txt) do sc query %%i > output.txt
echo Finished query services...
```

The above will loop through each of the 100 service names specified in serviceslist2.txt and output it to a file called output.txt in the same directory as the batch file

Comment: ...and overwrite output.txt, so only the last run will get logged. Using `>>` instead of `>` will solve this problem.