# Windows program files path names?

Tags: windows

Maybe this can be a silly question but I don't figure out how to search in google why in some code I read, it is used to write this way: `\\progra~1`

What does ~ and 1 mean?
I tried executing in Windows Run the same path but changing numbers and these are the results:

```
C:\progra~1 -> Opens Program Files
C:\progra~2 -> Opens Program Files(x86)
C:\progra~3 -> Opens ProgramData
C:\progra~4 -> Opens ProgramDevices, a folder I created in C:\
```

Why? Is this like a Match or something in the Folder names list?

For example a regex like `"progra"` and then to show the ~1 (First) match in some X order or ~2 (Second) ... etc?

Answer (score 3):

It's a compatability mode with the old (really old) windows 8.3 naming convention. The ~n represents the instance of the name that has the same root characters.

In your example:
Program Files and Program Files(x86) have the same root characters Progra.
Hence one gets progra~1, the next progra~2 etc.

8.3 compatability can be turned off for a disk partition.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, it's a pattern counter.
Check out also this answer: [What does %~d0 mean in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file)

You can find more examples of different variables with modifiers here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx
(ctrl-f for "Variable substitution")