# cmder.bat file opening cmder icon instead of conemu

Tags: conemu, cmder

I just downloaded cmder from github and tried running cmder.bat to start it but got an error that it couldn't find conemu in the `~dp0\vendor\maximus-5\conemu` folder.  I figured this was because the cmder devs don't want to include the conemu files in the git repo, and indeed the path wasn't there.  So I downloaded the latest release of conemu and edited the bat file to point to my conemu install, like this:

```
@echo off
SET CMDER_ROOT=%~dp0
start "G:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /Icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\icons\cmder.ico" /Title Cmder /LoadCfgFile "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\ConEmu.xml"
```

The error's gone but it just loads the cmder icon in a picture viewer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: You have to install cmder instead of cloning git sources!

Comment: The reason I wanted to try it this way is because cmder was very buggy with Vim from the regular install.  I don't see why this wouldn't work though.  Is there any mistake I'm making?  Isn't the start command just looking for a conemu install?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning [cmder sources](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) has no sense unless you are ready and able to "build" cmder with `scripts/build.ps1`. I do not see any reason for `Cmder.bat` existence, it's obsolete.

The preferable way:

- Install official versions of products [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/Downloads.html), [Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) and optionally [clink](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/releases) (if you really need it). Also, you may check [msys connector](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html).
- Or just unpack latest official relase of [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/releases).

Personally, I prefer official versions rather than third-party bundles.

Comment: I did that for conemu, but how do I get cmder to point to it?

Comment: All required links exist in answer