# How to change current directory inside IF statement and reference its path with environment variable CD?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, adb

I'm trying to install an app from my PC running Windows 10 using **adb** and I need to use command `cd` before I'm installing the app.

But I see a strange behavior. If I use the `cd` command before the `if` statement, it's working well. But if I use the `cd` command inside the `if` statement, it is not working.

Here is what I tried:

1. This one is working well:

   ```
   cd %~f0\..\..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk
   if "%arg1%" == "aaa" (
       adb install %CD%\sample_app-debug.apk
   )
   ```
2. This one results on execution in an error:

   ```
   if "%arg1%" == "aaa" (
       cd %~f0\..\..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk
       adb install %CD%\sample_app-debug.apk
   )
   ```

   The error output is:

   > Failed to stat
   >   C:\Users\ntuser\Documents\workspace\Team\script\sample_app-debug.apk:
   >   No such file or directory

   It looks like it did not do the `cd` command in this case.

Comment: What programming language is this, that uses round brackets to group statements?

Comment: @RenéPijl I'm new to batch files - but in all the examples that I saw the round brackets were used like that.

Comment: So this is a Windows batch file. What version of Windows? And why the different "ocr" and "aaa"?

Comment: @RenéPijl windows 10 and I changed the "ocr" to "aaa" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` encounters the beginning of a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)`, the entire block is preprocessed before the command left to the command block is executed at all. This means all environment variables using `%variable%` syntax are replaced by current value of the referenced environment variable before executing the command which later executes the entire command block. This behavior can be seen on running a batch file from within a command prompt window without `@echo off` being usually at top of the batch file.

This means on your batch file with the **IF** command and the command block to execute on condition being true that `%CD%` is replaced by current directory **before** the command **IF** is executed and so also **before** the command **CD** is executed at all.

There are two possibilities:

1. explicitly enable delayed environment variable expansion and reference the environment variable in the command block with using syntax `!variable!`
   or
2. don't use a command block by using **GOTO** or a subroutine and **CALL**.

Solution 1 with enabled delayed environment variable expansion:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%arg1%" == "aaa" (
    cd "%~dp0..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
    adb.exe install "!CD!\sample_app-debug.apk"
)
endlocal
```

Solution 2 with not using a command block at all and instead use **GOTO**:

```
if "%arg1%" == "aaa" goto AAA
rem Other commands
goto :EOF

:AAA
cd "%~dp0..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
adb.exe install "%CD%\sample_app-debug.apk"
goto :EOF
rem Or use a different GOTO to continue processing somewhere else in batch file.
```

Another solution 2 is using a subroutine and command **CALL**:

```
if "%arg1%" == "aaa" call :AAA
rem Other commands executed even if above condition is true.

rem Avoid a fall through to the subroutine below.
goto :EOF

:AAA
cd "%~dp0..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
adb.exe install "%CD%\sample_app-debug.apk"
rem Exit the subroutine and continue on line below calling it.
goto :EOF
```

But I think your code can be even more easier because it is most likely not necessary to specify the *.apk file with full path.

```
if "%arg1%" == "aaa" (
    cd "%~dp0..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
    adb.exe install sample_app-debug.apk
)
```

And perhaps also working is:

```
if "%arg1%" == "aaa" adb.exe install "%~dp0..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk\sample_app-debug.apk"
```

---

It is better to use here `%~dp0` which references the drive and path of the batch file ending with a backslash instead of `%~f0` which is the name of the batch file with file extension and full path.

For example with batch file being `C:\Temp\Test\Install.bat` the command line

```
cd "%~f0\..\..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
```

results in execution of

```
cd "C:\Temp\Test\Install.bat\..\..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
```

and the current directory is `C:\Temp\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk` after this command with in real invalid directory name `Install.bat` in path which is not a directory.

The command line

```
cd "%~dp0..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
```

is much better as it results in execution of

```
cd "C:\Temp\Test\..\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk"
```

which makes also `C:\Temp\apps\app_sample\samples\sample_app\build\outputs\apk` the current directory, but with a completely correct path in comparison to above `cd` command line.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` and `%~f0`.
- `cd /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?` ... explains delayed environment variable expansion on an **IF** and a **FOR** example.
- `setlocal /?`

I don't have **adb** installed. So I can only assume that it is an executable with file extension `.exe` and not a batch file with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd` which would require the usage of `call adb.bat ...` or `call adb.cmd ...` in this batch file.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried solution 1 and it worked. and I also tried you suggestion to install the app with the full path and it worked. You helped me a lot!