# How to pass an parameter with special characters from vbs to batch file without enclosing it in double quotes?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript, escaping, echo

I want pass an parameter with special characters from vbs to batch file without enclosing it in double quotes.
vbs:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "Test.bat ""0,(5306546...)"""
```

batch file:

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause > NUL
```

My goals is the output:

```
0,(5306546...)
```

And not:

```
"0,(5306546...)"
```

If the vbs were:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "Test.bat 0,(5306546...)"
```

L'output of the batch file would be:

```
0
```

This question is different because I didn't know the %~1 command before this answer.

Comment: Leave the quotes and strip them in the batch by using `Echo=%~0`

Comment: The use of the tilde in the answer below is documented in the `CALL` and `FOR` commands help files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does %~d0 mean in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use

```
echo %~1
```

in your batch?