# How to parse returned system variable %~d0 to return and store the current drive letter by itself without the colon character

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file, the following returns the drive letter and a colon.

```
set current_Drive=%~d0
echo %current_Drive%
```

I need to strip the colon from `%current_Drive%` so that the variable drive letter itself  ( "C" instead of "C:\" ) can be used to create a text file within the batch, such as-

```
dir/s > "Myfiles on Drive %current_Drive% .txt"
```

The colon (:) contained in the var `%current_Drive%` is not a legal character in filenames and needs to be stripped out.

I have tried modifying examples from:
[What does %~d0 mean in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: `echo %current_Drive:~0,1%`

Comment: There is documentation in `help set` and `help for`.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks, Solved another problem also. The syntax also functions to echo (LEFT,MID,RIGHT) string characters stored in a windows batch file local variable TYPE-- Example --
set _StringVar=%"abcdefg"
echo %tempvar:~4,2%

Comment: @Stephan please make an answer using your comment. Let's minimize unanswered questions count!

Comment: @JosefZ my opinion is that, as there are lots of substring-questions for batch file on SO, mark it as duplicate (and then delete it [poor duplicate]) instead of keeping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command has a few useful features for string manipulation, like [substring extraction](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) or [substring replacement](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

To get only the first character of a variable, use

```
echo %current_Drive:~0,1%
```

In `:~0,1`, `~` means "I want a substring", `0` means "skip `0` characters" and `1` means "take `1` character from here"

Note: this only works for environment variables `%var%`. It doesn't work with specials like `%0` or `for` variables `%%a` - you need to assign them to a "normal" variable first.

You could also remove the unwanted part `:\` with `echo %current_Drive::\=%` (replace `:\` with nothing), but I'd prefer the first method.

Another way (completely overkill for this task; just for completeness):
Split the string by the colon with a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ("%current_Drive%") do echo %%a
```

Advantage: you don't have to know the length of the substring, it takes everything from the start of the string to the delimeter.